# Unknown pdx type=4

Tags: java, gemfire, geode

My distributed `geode` system went just well before, but recently not, and I don't know whether it's relevant to the company's power-cut last night. It seems all geode data persisted before can not be deserialize back now.

here's the error information:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown pdx type=4
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.readPdxSerializable(InternalDataSerializer.java:3162)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicReadObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:2979)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.readObject(DataSerializer.java:3210)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.util.BlobHelper.deserializeBlob(BlobHelper.java:101)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl.deserialize(EntryEventImpl.java:1554)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl.deserialize(EntryEventImpl.java:1546)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.PreferBytesCachedDeserializable.getDeserializedValue(PreferBytesCachedDeserializable.java:67)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl.getOldValue(EntryEventImpl.java:723)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.validatedDestroy(LocalRegion.java:1146)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.destroy(LocalRegion.java:1130)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegion.destroy(AbstractRegion.java:315)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.remove(LocalRegion.java:9372)
    at com.igola.datahub.wwl.geode.WWLResultsDAO.removeByKey(WWLResultsDAO.java:276)
```

my project was build on play framework and my configuration of geode cache and region is like this:

```
cache.setIsServer(true);

    diskStorage = configuration.getString("geode.storage.name");
    String fileStorage = configuration.getString("geode.storage.path");
    cache.createDiskStoreFactory()
            .setDiskDirs(new File[]{new File(fileStorage)})
            .setDiskUsageWarningPercentage(0.8f)
            .setAutoCompact(true)
            .create(diskStorage);

geodeCache.getCache()
            .<DataKey, When2GoData>createRegionFactory(PARTITION_REDUNDANT_PERSISTENT_OVERFLOW)
            .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
            .setEntryIdleTimeout(new ExpirationAttributes(TIMEOUT_LONG, ExpirationAction.DESTROY))
            .setDiskStoreName(geodeCache.getDiskStorage())
            .setPartitionAttributes(new PartitionAttributesFactory<>()
                    .setRedundantCopies(REDUNDANT_COPIES)
                    .setPartitionResolver(new DataKey())
                    .create())
            .create("xxx");

cache = new CacheFactory()
            .set("locators", configuration.getString("geode.locator"))
            .set("name", configuration.getString("geode.name")+ "-"+ uuid)
            .set("mcast-port", "0")
            .set("log-level", "error")
            .setPdxPersistent(true)
            .setPdxReadSerialized(true)
            .create();
```

Comment: what should i do...

Comment: Get a UPS ..... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant code from the `readPdxSerializable` method:

```
PdxType pdxType = gfc.getPdxRegistry().getType(typeId);
if (logger.isTraceEnabled(LogMarker.SERIALIZER)) {
    logger.trace(LogMarker.SERIALIZER, "readPdxSerializable pdxType={}", pdxType);
}
if (pdxType == null) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown pdx type=" + typeId);
}
```

So it looks like you have something in your cache that you can no longer deserialize ... due (I think) the fact that the type is no longer registered in the type registry.